# Ajax: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to AJAX. I've looked at previous postings and see this is a common question. The usual answer is that the data isn't actually in JSON format. This is certainly true in my case - the correct response is preceded by other data from earlier echo output, like this:

```
<button type="button" id="dotest" name="dotest" >SAVE</button>{"foo":"bar"}
```

This is the test code that creates this output:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php include "../php/bin/test-bin.php"; ?>
<script src="../js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
$('#dotest').click(function(){testCode()});
function testCode()
{
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {testvar:true},
      url:'../php/bin/test-bin.php',
      success: function(formdata) {
       alert(formdata['foo']);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
      },
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
echo '<button type="button" id="dotest" name="dotest" >SAVE</button>';
if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'testvar'))
{
  $myArr = array("foo" => "bar");
  $json = json_encode($myArr);
  return;
}
```

If I move the echo button statement to the end of the PHP code, the unwanted text doesn't appear in the response.

Have I some error in my code? Or is there some way to flush the PHP output after echo calls? I've tried flush() but it doesn't work.

Any help you can give would be good for my blood pressure!

**EDIT**

I've done what's suggested and put the Ajax call in a separate file. I get the same problem. In testing I've removed almost all the code, leaving this (the requires and defines do nothing at this point):

```
<?php

// include global constants etc
require_once(__DIR__.'/../inc/config.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/../inc/errorhandler.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/../inc/common.php');

// fl_data
@define('FL_PREVVAL', 0);
@define('FL_CURRVAL', 1);

$data = array('animal' => 'horse', 'vehicle' => 'cart');
$json = json_encode($data);
echo $json;
```

The Ajax response is an error, but xhr.responseText contains correctly formatted JSON.

If I remove the two define statements, the response is success with the same data. Putting back any code preceding the echo produces the same error situation.

What am I doing wrong!

Comment: When sending an output as JSON response, simply, you cannot mix JSON with other data/markup etc... you have to get rid of the `echo` from the first line

Comment: alert(formdata); only what is u getting?

Comment: If you really want to use the same script for your include and your ajax call, you will have to distinguish between the different usages of your script. For example check if a POST request was made. However, using different scripts for different purposes probably makes more sense.

Comment: an `If` with a `return`? What were you thinking that would do?

Comment: @MohitKumar use console.log() if you want to know what data is in a variable.

Comment: To simply fix the issue of your code *as is*, just move the `echo` into the `else` of that `if filter`. That way the button html comes out if the file is just included. Then if its used in ajax, it spits out the json instead. However... I'd go a different route with this than that.

Comment: In regards to your question about possibly flushing output, you would have to wrap all of your `echo` in a large `ob_start` block, and then use the buffer accordingly. Which overcomplicates a basic situation where you really just need two different php files (one for html include, another for ajax handling).

Comment: Thank you all for your quick replies. This site is marvellous. If I've understood you all correctly, I need to move the PHP code of the Ajax call into a separate file that contains no other output. Can more than one Ajax call appear in that file or should I use one file for each call?

Comment: Might I ask a quick follow-up? When I put a breakpoint in the JS file on the $.ajax line, I see it is called twice, before the PHP file response is sent. What is happening here?

Comment: You can use one file for all your ajax calls. Just block off each specific ajax action (preferably with a class object of methods). However if your actions become plenty and large, breaking it into logical sub-files is wise for maintenance and readability. Regarding follow-up question, I do not see anything in the code you provided which would cause a double-ajax call.

Comment: "xhr.responseText contains correctly formatted JSON"...show us, so we can check :-) Because seemingly jQuery disagrees with you. What HTTP response code do you get btw? More than just formatting errors can cause the ajax call to fail

Comment: Fair enough. "Seems to contain" would have been more accurate. How do I extract the return data in a format that captures possible hidden characters?

Comment: just copy/paste. If you paste it into something like Notepad++ and turn on the show all characters setting it might show something up. Or the JSON still might not be valid for some other reason. Or like I said it just errored because of another problem - do you get a 200 OK response or not?

Comment: Apologies everyone. I'm unused to JS debugging. The response text is actually "\ufeff{\"animal\":\"horse\",\"vehicle\":\"cart\"}" with a utf-8 header  character. How do I handle this?

Comment: Check in the Network tab of your browser in the Response section of the ajax call, I suspect there you'll see the raw data, un-escaped. Does it really look like that? json_encode() doesn't put escape sequences in like that. And you still haven't answered my question about the HTTP response code.

Comment: @ADyson: Apologies for the omission. You're stretching my debugging skills. The Response headers of the network call don't include any mention of text (if it matters, I'm using Firefox). But looking at the xhr values in the debugger, the status is 200, statusText is "OK" and the responseText is as I quoted previously.   I've tried adding a Unicode character to the text in PHP and it's returned escaped (\u251e). Removing the first character of the responseText and running JSON.parse on it produces the array I would expect.

Comment: I'm talking about the view which looks like this: http://wiki.corejoomla.com/Debug_ajax_requests_using_Chrome_developer_tools (that's Chrome but it's very similar in Firefox). You have to click on the correct request of course, there may be many of them listed.

Comment: @ADyson Got it. Thanks again. You're being very patient. The response payload listed is {"animal":"ho\u215erse","vehicle":"cart"} but with a red dot before it.

Comment: I see. since you've hard-coded those values into your PHP I'd suggest that means the funny character was added by whatever you typed in PHP. Is the PHP file encoded in UTF-8 perhaps? Either way you should probably get rid of it and replace with an ASCII "o".

Comment: Also check if the web page itself is using utf8 (meta tag I think, you can google it)

Comment: @ADyson: Yes to UTF-8. Funny character \u215e was indeed added in my PHP script. It's Unicode for ⅞ (I'm having to transcribe a lot of Imperial measurements).

Comment: So does removing that fix it (since it looks like you didn't want that in the middle of the word "horse")? Or have I missed the point?

Comment: @ADyson: The web page itself is also UTF-8 according to the response meta tag. You'll see if you look back to my original question it's explicitly coded as such in the HTML template page. The odd character was inserted just to see what would happen to it. Removing it makes no difference. Please ignore it.

Comment: So you still have a problem about invalid JSON when you remove this character?

Comment: @ADyson: Yes. I still get the URF-8 header character in front of the JSON.

Comment: check the php file itself (any any PHP files which are included in this one via include statements (and of course any included children of _those_ scripts, and then keep going recursively down the hierarchy)) has no other special characters embedded e.g. before the `<?php` tag or after the `?>` - remember that anything at all which is outside the PHP tags will get sent directly in the output.

Comment: The scripts all being UTF-8 there are the usual EF BB BF characters before the <?php in every one. But nothing otherwise.

Comment: There's got to be something odd somewhere. The basic code on its own definitely doesn't produce that: https://eval.in/966070

Comment: @ADyson: **Problem solved**. It must, from what you have found, be somewhere else on my system. It turned out to be a fault in my source files. I resaved them all as text files instead of UTF-8 and the problem went away. Saving them as UTF-8 again didn't cause the problem to recur, so the original UTF-8 files must have been faulty in some way.  Thank you very much for your help, which has taught me a lot.